# Sendgrid white label email link produces warning

Tags: email, sendgrid

While using sendgrid white label email links our customers are receiving the following warning:

```
Suspicious link: this link leads to untrusted site.  Are you sure you want to proceed to emaillink.billiving.com?
```

Our subdomain emaillink.billiving.com is mapped to their DNS probably to capture some data. Any ideas for what could be the source of this issue?

Josh

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem due to an incorrect SPF record on the sender's email address.

Adding include:sendgrid.net before -all fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you please explain how you solved it ? We might add u a plus one if this helps us

Comment: Assuming you send emails from john@billiving.com through SendGrid, the SPF record for billliving.com needs to be changed. Edit the DNS for billiving.com, and look for the SPF record. It will end with ~all or -all. Just before that, add "include:sendgrid.net".